# Foreign key relationship

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm trying to setup a foreign key using the following two classes. 
I want to use pAcqType as an enum and store the names of the types in another table. How should I setup my classes to do this?

```
public class Property
{
    [Key]
    public int pID { get; set; }
    public string pAddress { get; set; }
    public string pCounty { get; set; }
    public string pCity { get; set; }
    public string pState { get; set; }
    public string pzip { get; set; }
    public virtual PropertyAcquisitionType pAcqType { get; set; }    <-- foreign key      
}

public class PropertyAcquisitionType
{
    [Key]        
    public int patID { get; set; }        
    public string patName { get; set; }
}
```

UPDATE

Dan got me thinking. And I tried the following and it seems to have worked out. 
It setup the foreign key on the table like I wanted. And it didn't even ask for an inverse on the other table.

```
    public int? pAcqType { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("pAcqType")]
    public PropertyAcquisitionType patID { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the foreign key required (`NOT NULL` in the database)?

```
public int pAcqTypeId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("pAcqTypeId")]
public virtual PropertyAcquisitionType pAcqType { get; set; }
```

Otherwise,

```
public int? pAcqTypeId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("pAcqTypeId")]
public virtual PropertyAcquisitionType pAcqType { get; set; }
```

Then in your other class, add an inverse relationship:

```
public class PropertyAcquisitionType
{
    [Key]        
    public int patID { get; set; }        
    public string patName { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("pAcqType")]
    public virtual ICollection<Property> pOfThisType { get; set; }
}
```

Here is one way you could define the relationship using the fluent API (without attributes in the entity classes). Note with this method, you should not need to add a `properties` property on the `PropertyAcquisitionType` entity to satisfy the inverse side of the relationship, because the `.WithMany()` tells EF what it needs to know:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Property>()
            .HasKey(x => x.pID)
            .HasRequired(x => x.pAcqType) // or HasOptional if using int?
            .WithMany() // or WithMany(x => x.pOfThisType) if you want to add / keep the inverse property
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.pAcqTypeId)
        ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'hoahelp.Models.PropertyAcquisitionType' and 'hoahelp.Models.Property'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.

Comment: it's being picky. The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'pAcqType' on type 'hoahelp.Models.Property' is not valid. The foreign key name 'PropertyAcquisitionTypeId' was not found on the dependent type 'hoahelp.Models.Property'. The Name value should be a comma separated list of foreign key property names.

Comment: @Prescient did you name the property `PropertyAcquisitionTypeId`, or did you name it something like `pAcqTypeId`? The value in the string has to match the name of the property in the class. If you named it `pAcqTypeId`, then you should use `[ForeignKey("pAcqTypeId")]`